# Why does the position method not return the expected values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the `position` method not return `[left: 100, top: 10]` in this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#parent1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 9px pink;
}

#child1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 5px green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://jquery-local/jquery.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log($('#child1').position());
    });
})(jQuery); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="parent1">
    <div id="child1"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is the only way to get the position via the `css` method?

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery source location is wrong.

try changing the jquery src to 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

or to the latest version
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Could be a perfectly valid address in his network.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uVCC/), I get

```
 left: 119
 top: 19
```

which accounts for the 10px top value plus the 9px border of the surrounding element.

`position()` may not be what you want, though - it retrieves the position *[relative to the offset parent.](http://api.jquery.com/position/)* In this case, it doesn't make a difference because there is no offset parent, but if you want the position in the document, use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me it returns: [117, 27].

First off, because the position of the child is relative to the parent, the child's coordinates are only relative from those of the parent. That means that any positioning of the parent, such as the default body margin, are added to the positioning of the child. Also, the border of the parent, another 9 px, is added. If you set the margin of the body to 0, the child's position is [109, 19] :)